# Why ST_DistanceSphere returns 0?

Tags: postgis, point, distance, st-distance

Why when I use `ST_DistanceSphere()` for obtain the distance in meters between to points I get 0 as result?

This is the query:

```sql
SELECT
    ST_DistanceSphere(ST_MakePoint(54.1098335, 7.9320379), ST_MakePoint(54.3598335, 8.1820379));
```

Comment: Your query is working for me

Comment: Which is the result in your case? What can be wrong in my case?

Comment: 39120. I dont know. What if you set srid? `SELECT ST_DistanceSphere(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(54.1098335 , 7.9320379),4326) ,ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(54.3598335 , 8.1820379),4326))` ?

Comment: No, also in this case the result is 0

Comment: The result for me is  `39119.83140282`. Perhaps there is something wrong with your PostGIS. Please run the example query from https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DistanceSphere.html. Do you get the same results?

Comment: I ran the query, and the only field that is wrong is dist_meters (which is 0), instead the others fields are the same

Comment: Checking on google maps the distance between the points is 32 km, how is possible that you get 39119 as result?

Comment: Please add the output from `SELECT postgis_full_version();`.

Comment: POSTGIS="3.2.0 c3e3cc0" [EXTENSION] PGSQL="130" GEOS="3.9.1-CAPI-1.14.2" PROJ="6.3.1" LIBXML="2.9.10" LIBJSON="0.13.1" LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.3" WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)"

Comment: Are we all measuring the same place? Google Maps, for some reason, assumes lat/lon when given decimal degrees, placing this at the North Sea. All GIS software assumes lon/lat which places this at the horn of Africa. With a geodisc measure of ~32, and ~39 km respectively. Though it doesn't help your issue, might help if we agree with the SRID and latitude so distortions are the same.

Comment: I think that my Postgis in broken, cause I can't find the error, how can I uninstall and reinstall it without broke eveything?

Comment: No one can help me? I get stuck at the moment

Comment: I removed Postgresql and PostGIS, I reinstalled everything and now is working